# How to retrieve new meta from the org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I have new classes, pages, etc in the my Salesforce org. Is it possible to update the project with all new files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [source:retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm) command.

Some of them are like:

1. To refresh and retrieve the files already pulled in source:

   ```
   sfdx force:source:retrieve -p path/to/source
   ```
2. To retrieve all Apex classes:

   ```
   sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass
   ```
3. To retrieve all custom objects and Apex classes:

   ```
   sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject,ApexClass
   ```

There are many other commands which you can find in documentation from link above